# Java visualvm missing tabs and disabled buttons

Tags: java, jvisualvm

I am trying to profile a remote java app using the visualvm. It connects to the app, but i have no Threads or Profile tabs (only overview, monitor and sampler) and the Perform GC, Heap Dump and all buttons from Sampler are disabled.

I have read the other posts about problems like this. I am using the same jdk for both the remote app and on my computer (1.6.0_25 on 64bit) and i have delted java.exe from windows/system32

Beside updating the java version, any other recommendations?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i was using jstad and expecting those features because of a bad tutorial. I switched to JMX and now it's ok.